Central Composite Design with RSM - number of replicates?
I am fairly new to design of experiments in general, and now I want to perform response surface modeling in combination with a Central Composite Design.
I have read a few times that the center points should be replicated for a number of reasons, one of which is estimation of pure experimental error. I have two questions about this:
(1) Why should only the center points be repeated?
(2) I can imagine that the (or one) answer to (1) might be "because repeating all the design points would be time consuming". Let's suppose my CCD has 27 points and I can repeat all the points X times. How do I proceed with the response surface model fitting? Should I try to fit a model to 27*X data points, or should I first take the average of X repetitions for each data point and then fit my model to the 27 (averaged) data points?

You can find some useful relevant discussion in our answers to closely related questions.

Thanks for your response, but as far as I can tell these questions have not been addressed in the closely related questions.

You really need to tell us some specifics of your situation, otherwise answers can only talk in generalities, and will not be very helpful. Pease do this as an edit to the post, as comments on this site are ephemeral and often seen by few people. Note that response-surface methodology often is used in an iterative fashion, with a sequence of experiments, targeting in on the max ... so using all your resources for the first iteration might not be wise
